# Enlightening proof that the algebraic numbers form a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

The proof I'm familiar with that the algebraic numbers $\mathbb A$ form a field uses the fact that the resultant of two polynomials $p,q\in\mathbb Q[x]$ satisfies the following properties:

- It is $0$ iff $p$ and $q$ have a common factor.
- It is a polynomial in the coefficients of $p$ and $q$.

We then introduce a new variable and cleverly manipulate $p$ and $q$ to get polynomials which vanish at the sums and products of their roots. This is in some ways a nice proof, e.g. it is constructive and so can be converted into an algorithm to find such polynomials (which I in fact just finished doing in C). But I don't find it very enlightening; it seems like the fact that $\mathbb A$ is a field is simply an accident. Is there a more enlightening proof of this fact?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155122, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277753

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If $a,b$ are algebraic then $[F(a,b):F]$ is finite so $a+b, ab \in F(a,b)$ are algebraic too. I find this proof to feel the most enlightening.

If you specifically wanted to see why the constructive proof is not merely an accident, then see [this](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/galois.html) link- after proving that the sum of algebraic numbers is algebraic in the usual way, they add:

> Now let us analyse the above argument a little. We see that what made it work was that the vector space of all rational combinations of powers of x+y was finite-dimensional. We then observe that we deduced this from the fact that the corresponding vector spaces for powers of x and powers of y were also finite-dimensional - and also that we could build a spanning set for the (x+y)-space out of the spanning sets for the x-space and the y-space.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was missing the fact that $[F(a,b):F(a)]$ is finite hence $[F(a,b):F]$ is. I'm not sure why that didn't occur to me.

Comment: "we could build a spanning set for the (x+y)-space out of the spanning sets for the x-space and the y-space." How?

Comment: In my opinion this standard proof is not constructive at all. It does not help us to find explicitly an algebraic equation for $a+b$ when we have found one for $a$ and $b$. It only shows the existence.

Answer (score 83):

My favourite proof of this goes through matrices.  A complex number is an eigenvalue of a square matrix of rational numbers if and only if it is algebraic (e.g. any monic polynomial has a  **companion matrix** of which it is the characteristic polynomial).
If $A$ is an invertible matrix with eigenvalue $\alpha$, then $A^{-1}$ has eigenvalue $1/\alpha$.
If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices with rational entries and eigenvalues $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for eigenvectors $u$ and $v$ respectively, then $A \otimes B$ and $A \otimes I + I \otimes B$ have eigenvalues $\alpha \beta$ and $\alpha + \beta$ for eigenvector
$u \otimes v$.

This also shows, BTW, that the algebraic integers are closed under addition and multiplication: they are the eigenvalues of matrices with integer entries.

Comment: +1. This proof is constructive and also works for ring extensions, it shows that the set of integral elements is a subring.

Comment: Beautiful proof.

Comment: Robert Israel, can you explain in more detail on how to calculate companion matrix of Kronecker symbol like $A\otimes B, A\otimes I+I\otimes B$, and post it on question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277753/question-in-algebraic-closed-field? Thanks.

Comment: @Eugene See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/713394/242) for a simpler more concrete approach (high-school accessible, requiring no knowledge of tensor or Kronecker products

Answer (score 20):

I find another charming proof in [*Lectures on the theory of algebraic numbers*](http://books.google.com.tw/books/about/Lectures_on_the_Theory_of_Algebraic_Numb.html?id=QEocn1kbfxAC&redir_esc=y) by **Hecke**.

It is constructive in appearance but is impractical in fact.
Let $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ be two polynomials with rational coefficients and roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$, respectively. Let $\{\alpha_i\mid i=0,\ldots,m\}$ and $\{\beta_j\mid j=0,\ldots,n\}$ be their conjugates, i.e. roots of $p$ and $q$ respectively. Then set $$r(x)=\prod_{i=0}^m\prod_{j=0}^n(x-\alpha_i-\beta_j).$$ We know that $\alpha+\beta$ is a root of $r(x)$ and that coefficients of $r(x)$ are symmetric functions of roots of $p$ and $q$, and hence could be written as polynomials of coefficients of the two polynomials, thus is rational. Therefore $\alpha+\beta$ is also algebraic. A similar proof goes for products. Finally, write $$p(x)=\sum_0^ma_ix^i.$$Then $$\sum_0^ma_i\alpha^i=0,$$ so that $$\sum_0^ma_{m-i}\alpha^{-i}=0,$$ and hence $\alpha^{-1}$ also is algebraic.
Inform me of any ambiguity or error, thanks.

Comment: If we replace $\mathbb{Q}$ by an arbitrary field, this proof only works for separable $\alpha,\beta$, right? Or can it be modified?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I cannot see the reason it only works for separable numbers: it does not use Galois theory at all; rather, it makes use of the fundamental theorem of symmetric functions. Per chance this works only for separable extensions? In any case, thanks for your attention.

Comment: This is the "other" approach to finding a polynomial for $\alpha+\beta$, that of using resultants. Your $r(x)$ is essentially Res$_y(p(y),$Res$_z(q(z),x-y-z))$.

Answer (score -1):

I am surprised that no one has suggested the following approach, which circumvents the verification of field axioms (more precisely, the job is delegated to the proof of some other proposition):
It suffices to show

**Claim.** Let $K$ be an extension field of a field $F$ and let $E$ be the set of all elements in $K$ that are algebraic over $F$. Then 
$E$=$F(E)$.

*Proof.* By definition $E\subset F(E)$. Because every element of $E$ is algebraic over $F$, $F(E)$ is an algebraic extension of $F$. Therefore, $F(E)\subset E$ by the definition of $E$. $\square$

Comment: I don't think this circumvents anything; you still need to show that $F(E)$ is an algebraic extension, which comes down to showing that sums and products of algebraic numbers are algebraic.

Comment: @Slade I am not sure about what you say. I learn field theory from Chapter V of Hungerford's *Algebra*, where the theorem "$F(E)$ is algebraic" (Theorem 1.12.) precedes the "algebraic elements form a field" theorem (Theorem 1.14.), and the proof of the former does not use the latter, so I think my argument isn't circular.

Comment: I didn't say anything about the field axioms, but the proof of 1.14 is literally just an application of 1.12. The real work, which we can't circumvent, happens in the proof of 1.12.

Comment: @Slade Do you mean that the field axioms ultimately have to be verified somewhere? By "circumvent" I mean that my argument makes full use of 1.12, thereby avoiding verifying the field axioms for a second time, while the common proof (like the one given by Ragib Zaman here and the one in Hungerford's book) does exactly what mine avoids. Both approaches are simple applications of 1.12, but I think mine is simpler.

Comment: I don't see the "double verification" you're talking about in Ragib's proof.

Comment: I see. The common proof uses "$E$ is a *finite* set of algebraic elements$\implies$ $F(E)$ is algebraic", whose proof does not require verification of the field axioms, while mine uses "$E$ is a set of algebraic elements$\implies$ $F(E)$ is algebraic", which hinges on the structure theorem of $F(X)$ (in Hungerford's *Algebra* it is Theorem 1.3), whose proof verifies the field axioms. So there is no circumvention or double verification: my argument delegates the verification to the proof of some other proposition, while the common proof verifies field axioms because it uses a weaker result.