# Set of algebraic integer form a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

An algebraic integer is a complex number that is the root of monic polynomial with integer coefficients.
Show that the set of algebraic integers is a subring of $C$.
(Hint: Use symmetric function theorem).

I also know that $\alpha \in$ $C$ is an algebraic integer if and only if $m_\alpha,_Q \in Z[x].$

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The most explicit proof that $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is a ring is with the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Number_theory). I'm not sure what means using the symmetric function theorem, can you elaborate on what you proved earlier ?

Comment: what is the meaning of $m_\alpha,_Q $?

Comment: $m_\alpha,_Q$ is minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over  field $Q$

Comment: This link may help you, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155122/how-to-prove-that-the-sum-and-product-of-two-algebraic-numbers-is-algebraic

Comment: See [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/713394/242) for a couple standard ways.

Answer (score 10):

Let $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}$ be algebraic integers; e.g. $\alpha^3+\alpha+1=0$ and $\beta^2+1=0$.

Since the polynomials that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ satisfy are monic, we can, by division, write any element of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]$ as an integer combination of elements of the basis, $B$:
$$
\left\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\beta,\alpha\beta,\alpha^2\beta\right\}\tag1
$$
That is, we can write any $p\in\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]$ as
$$
p=\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix}p_0&p_1&p_2&p_3&p_4&p_5\end{bmatrix}}^{\mathbb{Z}^n}\overbrace{\ \begin{bmatrix}1\\\alpha\\\alpha^2\\\beta\\\alpha\beta\\\alpha^2\beta\end{bmatrix}\ }^B\tag2
$$
which means we can write
$$
\begin{align}
p\ \begin{bmatrix}1\\\alpha\\\alpha^2\\\beta\\\alpha\beta\\\alpha^2\beta\end{bmatrix}
&=\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
p_{0,0}&p_{0,1}&p_{0,2}&p_{0,3}&p_{0,4}&p_{0,5}\\
p_{1,0}&p_{1,1}&p_{1,2}&p_{1,3}&p_{1,4}&p_{1,5}\\
p_{2,0}&p_{2,1}&p_{2,2}&p_{2,3}&p_{2,4}&p_{2,5}\\
p_{3,0}&p_{3,1}&p_{3,2}&p_{3,3}&p_{3,4}&p_{3,5}\\
p_{4,0}&p_{4,1}&p_{4,2}&p_{4,3}&p_{4,4}&p_{4,5}\\
p_{5,0}&p_{5,1}&p_{5,2}&p_{5,3}&p_{5,4}&p_{5,5}
\end{bmatrix}}^{\mathbb{Z}^{n\times n}}
\begin{bmatrix}1\\\alpha\\\alpha^2\\\beta\\\alpha\beta\\\alpha^2\beta\end{bmatrix}\tag3\\[6pt]
pB&=MB\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Since $M$ satisfies its characteristic polynomial
$$
{\large\chi}_M(M)=0\tag5
$$
we have that $p$ also satisfies ${\large\chi}_M$:
$$
{\large\chi}_M(p)=0\tag6
$$
Since ${\large\chi}_M$ is a monic integer polynomial, $p$ must be an algebraic integer.

---

**Example 1**

For example,
$$
(\alpha+\beta)\begin{bmatrix}1\\\alpha\\\alpha^2\\\beta\\\alpha\beta\\\alpha^2\beta\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\\alpha\\\alpha^2\\\beta\\\alpha\beta\\\alpha^2\beta\end{bmatrix}
$$
and ${\large\chi}_M(\lambda)=\det(M-I\lambda)=\lambda^6+5\lambda^4+2\lambda^3+4\lambda^2-4\lambda+1$.

Thus, $\alpha+\beta$ is an algebraic integer.

---

**Example 2**

Furthermore,
$$
\alpha\beta\ \begin{bmatrix}1\\\alpha\\\alpha^2\\\beta\\\alpha\beta\\\alpha^2\beta\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\\alpha\\\alpha^2\\\beta\\\alpha\beta\\\alpha^2\beta\end{bmatrix}
$$
and ${\large\chi}_M(\lambda)=\det(M-I\lambda)=\lambda^6-2\lambda^4+\lambda^2+1$.

Thus, $\alpha\beta$ is an algebraic integer.

---

**Conclusions**

The key points that can be extrapolated from the examples above are that

(1) since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ both satisfy monic integer polynomials, $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]$ can be written as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module generated by the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product#Connection_with_the_Kronecker_product) (or flattened outer product) of $\left\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\dots,\alpha^{k-1}\right\}$ and $\left\{1,\beta,\beta^2,\dots,\beta^{m-1}\right\}$.

(2) the action of $p\in\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]$ on the basis of $n=km$ generators, from the Kronecker product above, can be represented by $M\in\mathbb{Z}^{n\times n}$.

(3) since $M$ satisfies its own characteristic polynomial, ${\large\chi}_M(M)=0$, so does $p$, ${\large\chi}_M(p)=0$

(4) the characteristic polynomial of an integer matrix is a monic integer polynomial.

Therefore, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic integers, then each $p\in\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]$ is an algebraic integer.

Comment: Compare [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/713394/242). $\ \ $