# Is $5^{1/5} - 3\cdot i$ algebraic?

Tags: complex-numbers, algebraic-numbers

I am studying the book *Complex Variables with Applications* written by Herb Silverman. In this book, problem number 8 in Question 1.7 is as in the following.

> Is $5^{1/5} - 3\cdot i$ algebraic? (i.e, Is the $5$th-root of $5$ minus $3\cdot i$ algebraic?)

Can you help me to solve this?

Comment: You should edit you question and include what your thoughts are so far, what you've tried etc. Also, algebraic over what? Algebraic over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: "Algebraic" by itself means "algebraic over the rationals".

Comment: Would that by any chance be this MIT Open Courseware? https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-04-complex-variables-with-applications-fall-1999/

Answer (score 2):

> - The number $5^{1/5}$ is algebraic since it is a zero of $z^5-5$.
> - The number $-3i$ is algebraic since it is a zero of $z^2+9$.
> - The sum of algebraic numbers is algebraic. See for instance *[this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155122/how-to-prove-that-the-sum-and-product-of-two-algebraic-numbers-is-algebraic)*.
>
> We conclude: $5^{1/5}-3i$ is algebraic.

Comment: This is a nice, and simple solution. Well done!

Comment: @TobyMak: Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Of course $\root 5 \of 5 - 3i$ is an algebraic number, and more than that, it is an algebraic integer. $\root 5 \of 5$ is an algebraic integer of degree 5 from the field of algebraic numbers $\mathbb Q(\root 5 \of 5)$, and $-3i$ is an algebraic integer from $\mathbb Z[i]$.

So then what field of algebraic numbers contains both $\root 5 \of 5$ and $-3i$? This goes beyond your question, but you might run into it later, if not in Silverman's book, in another book. $\mathbb Q(\root 5 \of 5, i)$ is a ring of algebraic degree 10, and the minimal polynomial of $\root 5 \of 5 - 3i$ is $x^{10} + 45x^8 +$ $\ldots +$ $32805x^2 - 4050x + 59074$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=\sqrt[5]5-3i$. Then\begin{align}a=\sqrt[5]5-3i\iff&a+3i=\sqrt[5]5\\\iff&(a+3i)^5=5\\\iff&a^5+15ia^4-90a^3-270ia^2+405a-5+243i=0.\end{align}So, if you define $p(x)=x^5-90x^3+405x-5$ and $q(x)=15x^4-270x^2+243$, $a$ is a root of $p(x)+q(x)i$. That is, $p(a)=-q(a)i$. But then $p^2(a)=-q^2(a)$. So, $a$ is a root of $p^2(x)+q^2(x)$.

---

This answer was completed with the help of the comments of the user Michael.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout My mistake. Is it clear now?

Comment: I think you have to be tricksier than that.  From line 2 to 3 it seems that (a-3i)^5=5, but a-3i = 5^(1/5)-6i, whose fifth power isn't 5.

Comment: It seems $(a+3i)^2=(a+3i)(a-3i)$

Comment: If $(a+3i)^5=5$, then $\overline{(a+3i)^5}=\overline5$. But $\overline{(a+3i)^5}=(\overline{a+3i})^5=(a-3i)^5$ and $\overline5=5$. Therefore $\bigl((a+3i)(a-3i)\bigr)^5=25$.

Comment: @TobyMak **Of course** they have different roots. Why do you think I've put a $\implies$ sign there instead of a $\iff$?

Comment: $\overline{a+3i}=\overline{a}-3i$, not $a-3i$ because $a$ is complex.

Comment: @Michael You're right. I'll either edit or delete my answer.

Comment: Don't delete it, it shows the work you have done, as cansomeonehelpmeout asked.  Expand the degree five polynomial, put those terms with $i$ on one side; then square both sides.  That gets rid of the $i$, and leaves a degree-10 with integer coefficients.

Comment: @Michael Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Multinomial Combiniations of Algebraic Integers**

Given a set of monic polynomials defining a set of algebraic integers, how can we derive a polynomial for a multinomial combination of those algebraic integers?

For example, given $\alpha^2-3=0$ and $\beta^3-2=0$, how do we derive a polynomial for $\alpha+\beta$?

First, create the basis for all multinomial combinations of $\alpha$ and $\beta$:
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
\alpha\\
\beta\\
\alpha\beta\\
\beta^2\\
\alpha\beta^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Next compute $(\alpha+\beta)B$:
$$
\begin{align}
(\alpha+\beta)B
&=(\alpha+\beta)
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
\alpha\\
\beta\\
\alpha\beta\\
\beta^2\\
\alpha\beta^2
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha+\beta\\
\alpha^2+\alpha\beta\\
\alpha\beta+\beta^2\\
\alpha^2\beta+\alpha\beta^2\\
\alpha\beta^2+\beta^3\\
\alpha^2\beta^2+\alpha\beta^3
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha+\beta\\
3+\alpha\beta\\
\alpha\beta+\beta^2\\
3\beta+\alpha\beta^2\\
\alpha\beta^2+2\\
3\beta^2+2\alpha
\end{bmatrix}\\[6pt]
&=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&1&0&0&0\\
3&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&3&0&0&1\\
2&0&0&0&0&1\\
0&2&0&0&3&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
\alpha\\
\beta\\
\alpha\beta\\
\beta^2\\
\alpha\beta^2
\end{bmatrix}
=MB
\end{align}
$$
$M$ is an integer matrix since the polynomials for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are monic.

Since multiplication by a scalar commutes with matrix multiplication, induction gives
$$
(\alpha+\beta)^kB=M^kB
$$
SInce $M$ satisfies its own characteristic polynomial,
$$
0=P(M)B=P(\alpha+\beta)B
$$
therefore, $\alpha+\beta$ also satisfies the characteristic polynomial of $M$:
$$
P(x)=x^6-9x^4-4x^3+27x^2-36x-23
$$
Since the characteristic polynomial, $P(x)=\det(M-Ix)$, for an integer matrix is monic, $\alpha+\beta$ is also an algebraic integer.

---

**Application to the Question**

The example above should be general enough to show how to apply the process to any set of monic polynomials, a cubic and quadratic were used to reduce the footprint of the example.

To show that $5^{1/5}-3i$ is an algebraic integer, apply the program above to $\alpha^5-5=0$ and $\beta^2+9=0$ to produce a monic polynomial for $\alpha-\beta$:
$$
x^{10}+45x^8+810x^6-10x^5+7290x^4+900x^3+32805x^2-4050x+59074
$$

---

**Afterword**

I had thought I had written something along these lines before. I finally came across [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3851456) that I wrote a while back. Hopefully, between this post and that one, the ideas are sufficiently clear.