# Finding a connection between the minimal polynomials of $a$, $b$ and $a-b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, minimal-polynomials

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero,
and let $a,b$ be algebraic over $k$, with minimal polynomials $f_a,f_b$, respectively, of the same prime degree $p \geq 3$. Denote: $f_a=T^p+a_{p-1}T^{p-1}+\cdots+a_1T+a_0$ and 
$f_b=T^p+b_{p-1}T^{p-1}+\cdots+b_1T+b_0$.
Further assume that $a-b$ has also minimal polynomial of degree $p$ over $k$,
denote it by $f_{a-b}=T^p+c_{p-1}T^{p-1}+\cdots+c_1T+c_0$.
Further assume that $k(a)=k(b)=k(a-b)$.

> Is there an explicit connection between the three minimal polynomials?

Thank you very much!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277753/question-in-algebraic-closed-field. The minimal polynomial will be a divisor of any polynomial that has $a + b$ as a root.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question in Algebraic closed field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277753/question-in-algebraic-closed-field)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. Please do not delete them. I will edit my question to a more specific one.

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331017/enlightening-proof-that-the-algebraic-numbers-form-a-field

Comment: Thanks! The third link seems very helpful (I will read it carefully).

Comment: If I am not wrong: The minimal polynomial of $a-b$, $f_{a-b}$, divides  $r$, the resultant of $f_a$ and $f_{-b}$ (since $r(a-b)=0$), and is of degree $p^2$. However, I do not see how to find $f_{a-b}$. (The section "number theory" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant is relevant).