# Closure of Algebraic Closure

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

**Prove that the algebraic closure of Q is closed under multiplication.**

So I assume Q is the rational numbers here because this wouldn't apply to any field and to prove it is closed under multiplication then if x,y ∈ Q, then xy ∈ Q.

I understand the definition and existance of algebraic closure for every field but am confused as how to apply the definition on how to prove the problem.

edit: i assume i prove the algebraic closure of Q is algebraic numbers which is a field, so i have to prove two parts but how would i proceed for each of those parts?

Comment: Concretely $\gamma$ is algebraic iff $\Bbb{Q}[\gamma]$ is a finite dimensional vector space, if $\alpha,\beta$ are algebraic then $\Bbb{Q}[\alpha,\beta]$ is a finite dimensional vector space so all its elements are algebraic.

Comment: The wording of your question confuses me. Anyway, if what you want is to show that algebraic numbers form a field, you may see [this excellent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1283161) by Robert Israel.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you know some basic facts on field theory. I will prove that a multiplication of two algebraic numbers is again an algebraic number.

Let $\alpha$, $\beta$ be algebraic numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$. If you can show $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha \beta):\mathbb{Q}]$ is finite, then you get $\alpha\beta$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. Observe that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\beta)\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$, so we will prove that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}]$ is finite instead.

Let $n$ and $m$ be a degree of an minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively. Then $\{1,\alpha,\cdots, \alpha^{n-1}\}$ and $\{1,\beta,\cdots,\beta^{m-1}\}$ are bases of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ respectively. Now, you can see that the set
$$\{\alpha^k\beta^l \mid 0\le k<n,\, 0\le l<m\}$$
generates $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$; that is, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ is generated by a finite set.

---

The OP points out that my proof only shows the set of all algebraic numbers is closed under multiplication, and we do not know the set of all algebraic numbers is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$. It may depend on the definition of algebraic closure, but the question is meaningful if we define algebraic closure of $F$ as *the least algebraically closed field containing $F$*.

In fact, the field of algebraic numbers is algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$. (The similar thing holds even if we replace $\mathbb{Q}$ to any general field.)
Let me describe its proof:  Let $\alpha$ be a solution of an equation
$$\beta_n x^n+\cdots \beta_1 x+\beta_0=0,$$
where $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$, $\cdots$, $\beta_n$ are algebraic numbers. From this, we can conclude that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta_0,\cdots ,\beta_n):\mathbb{Q}(\beta_0,\cdots,\beta_n)]$ is finite (in fact, it is less than or equal to $n$.) By applying the previous argument repeatedly, we can also see that $[\mathbb{Q}(\beta_0,\cdots,\beta_n):\mathbb{Q}]$ is also finite.  Therefore, $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta_0,\cdots,\beta_n):\mathbb{Q}]$ is finite.

Especially, we know that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta_0,\cdots,\beta_n)$, so $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]$ is also finite. This proves $\alpha$ is algebraic.

---

Therefore, we can see that the field of algebraic numbers is algebraically closed.

What can be inferred from this? Observe that every algebraically closed field $K$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$ also contains a copy of the field of algebraic numbers. (Just collect all solutions of equation with rational coefficients in $F$.)

Therefore, we can conclude that the field of all algebraic numbers is the *least algebraically closed field containing $\mathbb{Q}$!*. Hence the field of algebraic numbers is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: how would i show that the algebraic closure of Q is the alebraic number tho?

Comment: @jamesblack I don't understand your question. Do you mean every elements of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: you proved that algebraic numbers is closed under multiplication, but i have to first show that the algebraic closure of the field of rational numbers is algebraic numbers, right? how would i show that? i am not sure if my questio nmeans the same as what you stated, thanks

Comment: @jamesblack You can also prove that the field of algebraic numbers is algebraically closed (i.e. every polynomial of algebraic coefficients has an algebraic solution.) Moreover, every algebraically closed field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ also contains (a copy of) the field of algebraic numbers. This proves the field of all algebraic numbers is in fact an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: sorry that confused me more...could you briefly explain that by adding a small explanation into your answer on how these will prove my result?

Comment: @jamesblack I will give a proof of my assertion and a bit more explanation.

Comment: great, thank you! sorry for the troubles

Comment: @jamesblack I just finished to add more details. I hope it is helpful.

Comment: thank you so much , it is very helpful; what do you mean by the definition though? like is there a definition which will make this extra proof trivial? if so, what is the specific definition

Comment: @jamesblack We may simply take the algebraic closure of $F$ as a collection of all algebraic numbers. In this case, my argument shows algebraic closure of a field is algebraically closed.

Answer (score 0):

> this wouldn't apply to any field

Not so! The following is actually true:

**Theorem** Let $F$ be any field. Then there exists a field $K$ containing $F$ such that:

1. $K$ is algebraically closed,
2. Every element of $K$ is algebraic over $F$.

Moreover, $K$ is unique up to isomorphism; it is called the *algebraic closure* of $F$.

But this is besides the point. What you need to show is the following:

**Claim** Let $S$ be the set of complex numbers which are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $S$ is closed under multiplication.

Here's one strategy you can try:

1. Take two elements $s_1, s_2 \in S$. We aim to show that $s_1 s_2 \in S$.
2. Find a polynomial $p \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ which has both $s_1$ and $s_2$ as roots.
3. Let $K$ be the subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ generated by $\mathbb{Q}$ and the roots of $p$; prove that $K$ is finite-dimensional as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.
4. Prove that every subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ which is finite-dimensional as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space is a subset of $S$.
5. Since $s_1 s_2 \in K$, conclude that $s_1 s_2 \in S$.

Comment: i am saying this wouldnt apply to any field as in the closure of multiplication is that not ture?