# A question regarding properties of Algebraic Integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am trying questions of Field theory from Thomas Hungerford and couldn't solve this question exercise 18 of Section 5.1 .

[image]

I have done (a), (b) but couldn't do any of parts of (c) , (d) .

I tried using definition of algebraic integer by assuming a polynomial p(x) in $\mathbb{Z}(x) $ and trying to prove that there will exist an polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}(x) $ with required properties but couldn't for any parts of (c) and (d).

Can you please tell how to solve any part of (c) or(d) . Rest I would like to try by myself.

Thanks!!

Comment: @James https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1277753/how-to-prove-that-algebraic-numbers-form-a-field

Answer (score 2):

For the part (c), consider $P(X-n)$ and $n^d P(\frac{X}{n})$ where $P$ is a monic polynomial of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ vanishing $u$ and $d$ its degree.

The results of the question (d) is well-known but I don't know if there is simple answer. The classical proof consists in proving that $u$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if the subring $\mathbb{Z}[u]$ is finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}$. There exists an alternative proof based on the resultant which produce an explicit equation, see the question [How to prove that the sum and product of two algebraic numbers is algebraic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155122/how-to-prove-that-the-sum-and-product-of-two-algebraic-numbers-is-algebraic).