# Prove that the sum $ \sqrt{1001^2 + 1}+\sqrt{1002^2 + 1} \ + ... + \sqrt{2000^2 + 1}$ is irrational

Tags: polynomials, summation, contest-math, irrational-numbers, algebraic-numbers

> Prove that the sum $$ \sqrt{1001^2 + 1}+\sqrt{1002^2 + 1} \ + ... + \sqrt{2000^2 + 1}$$
> is irrational.

The textbook has the solution too but I'm unable to understand it.

The strategy is divided into two parts:-

- Proving that the sum is not an integer
- Proving that it is a zero of a monic polynomial

First part is simple to understand and prove.
$$n^2 +1 < n^2 +2 < n^2 + 2n\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 = (n+\frac{1}{n})^2\,.$$
So $$S = 1001 +a_1 + 1002 + a_2 + \ ... \ +2000 + a_{1000}\,, $$
and $$0 <a_1 + a_2 + ...+a_{1000} < \frac{1}{1001} (1000) < 1\,.$$

But how is the second part going to help in proving the result?

Comment: what is the "..."?

Comment: Is it $\sqrt{1001^2 + 1}+\sqrt{1002^2 + 1} \ + ... + \sqrt{2000^2 + 1}$?

Comment: Yeah! The last number is 2000

Comment: The second part probably uses the result: "If $P(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, and $\frac{a}{b}$ is a rational root of $P(x)$ then $b$ divides the leading coefficient of $P(x)$ and $a$ divides the constant term of $P(x)$". Can you prove this result?

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3: the result is true only if the fraction is irreducible.

Comment: @Bernard of course, the fraction has to be irreducible. Thank you for adding that. :-)

Comment: I have added a complete answer

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3 That's the Rational Root Theorem. Thanks!

Comment: See also https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q2h164239p915807.  An explicit polynomial with integer coefficients with $S$ as a root is given there.

Comment: Please could you rewrite the sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sqrt{n^2+1}$ is an algebraic integer for $n=1001,\dots,2000$ and [algebraic integers are closed under addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer), it follows that
$$S=\sqrt{1001^2 + 1}+\sqrt{1002^2 + 1} \ + ... + \sqrt{2000^2 + 1}$$
is algebraic integer too. Now use the fact that any rational algebraic integer IS an integer. This contradicts the fact that $S$ is NOT an integer (as you have already shown). Hence $S$ is not rational.

Answer (score 2):

A root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients is called an algebraic integer. For example, $\sqrt{n}$ is an algebraic integer, because it is a root of $X^2 - n$.  An important result is that the algebraic integers form a ring, i.e. the sum and product of algebraic integers is an algebraic integer.  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331017/enlightening-proof-that-the-algebraic-numbers-form-a-field/331027#331027) for my favourite proof of this fact.