# Sum and product of algebraic numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I have encountered the following problem:

> Let $L/K$ be a field extension and let $\alpha, \beta \in L$. Show that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic over $K$ if and only if $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha\beta$ are algebraic over $K$.

For the forward implication I have already seen several ways to show it, but I cannot think of a way for the other direction.

Comment: To be precise, you want to prove if $\alpha+\beta$ and $\alpha\beta$ are algebraic then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic over $K$..

Comment: Forwards, other...these are confusing terms: what exactly have you done and what you still have to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that the sum and product of two algebraic numbers is algebraic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155122/how-to-prove-that-the-sum-and-product-of-two-algebraic-numbers-is-algebraic)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $a$ and $b$ are the roots of the polynomial
$$
f(x)=x^2-(a+b)x+ab, 
$$
 $[K(a,b):K(a+b,ab)]$ is finite.
Hence we have 
$$
[K(a,b):K]=[K(a,b):K(a+b,ab)] \cdot [K(a+b,ab):K].
$$
Assuming that $ab$ and $a+b$ are algebraic, the right hand side is finite, and hence also the left hand side, so that $a,b$ are algebraic.

Comment: Is this still valid if the field extensions of $K$ are infinite fields?

Comment: Yes, think for example of $K=\mathbb{Q}$, which is an infinite field.

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha^2+\beta^2=(\alpha+\beta)^2-2\alpha\beta$

$(\alpha-\beta)^2=\alpha^2+\beta^2-2\alpha\beta$

$\alpha=\dfrac{\alpha+\beta+\alpha-\beta}{2}$

$\beta=\dfrac{\alpha+\beta-(\alpha-\beta)}{2}$