# If $\alpha$ is algebraic, then so is $\alpha^2 + \alpha$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\alpha\in L$ be algebraic over $K$ in a field extension $L\supseteq K$, i.e. there exists a polynomial $0\neq f\in K[X]$ which suffices $f(\alpha)=0$.

Is there an elementary way to prove that in this case, $\alpha^2+\alpha$ is also algebraic?

Comment: You can prove more generally that if $\alpha, \beta$ are algebraic then so are $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha \beta$; these are both good exercises. Then by induction it follows that if $\alpha$ is algebraic then so is any polynomial $g(\alpha)$ in it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/155122/

Comment: Yes.  Since $K(\alpha^2 + \alpha) \subset K(\alpha)$, the dimension of $K(\alpha^2 + \alpha)$ as a $K$ vector space must be finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Let $\beta=\alpha^2+\alpha$.

$\alpha$ is algebraic implies that
$$[K(\alpha):K]=n< \infty$$
for some $n$. Now show that $1,\beta, \beta^2,..., \beta^n \in K[\alpha]$ cannot be linearly independent over $K$.

Comment: Seems to me that the same proof applies if $\,\beta\,$ is any polynomial in $\,\alpha.$

Comment: @Somos Any polynomial in $\alpha$ with coefficients in $K$.