# Are the algebraic numbers dense in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: general-topology, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Since rational numbers are real algebraic numbers, clearly the real algebraic numbers must be dense in $\mathbb{R}$. So it seems natural to ask: are the (complex) algebraic numbers dense in $\mathbb{C}$? If not, is the (topological) closure of the algebraic numbers known?

Comment: Here's a proof: the algebraic complex numbers are closed under addition, and for every algebraic real $\alpha$ both $\alpha+0i$ and $0+\alpha i$ are algebraic complex numbers. So $\alpha+\beta i$ is an algebraic complex number whenever $\alpha,\beta$ are algebraic real numbers, and so the density  of the algebraic complex numbers in $\mathbb{C}$ follows from the density of the algebraic real numbers in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: (Note that this proof isn't quite as immediate as it may first appear since the fact that algebraicity is closed under addition used in the first sentence is surprisingly nontrivial - see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155122/how-to-prove-that-the-sum-and-product-of-two-algebraic-numbers-is-algebraic).)